# Ruby on Rails link_to With put Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm new to Rails, and I'm trying to use the link_to helper to create a link that issues a PUT request instead of a GET request. Specifically, I'm trying to create a link that activates a user's account in my app from the admin's panel. I'm using Rails 3.0.5.

My routes.rb file has:

```
match '/admin/users/:id/activate' => 'admin#activate_user',
  :action => :activate_user, :via => :put
```

My view has:

```
link_to 'Activate', :action => :activate_user, :id => user.id, :method => :put
```

However this generates the URL (for example) `/admin/users/7/activate?method=put` with the source code `<a href="/admin/users/7/activate?method=put">Activate</a>`.

I'd like to generate, instead, `<a href = "/admin/users/7/activate" data-method="put">Activate</a>`

I realize I could use button_to, but I've been wrestling with this issue for a while and I'm confused why I'm seeing this behavior, when other tutorials say that what I'm doing should be valid. How can I go about creating a link_to helper with the behavior I want?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Updated** - The `link_to` helper will do a GET unless a method is specified.

Its better specifying the exact request type, instead of `match` in your routes file. How about replacing `match` by `put` in routes as :

```
put '/admin/users/:id/activate' => 'admins#activate_user', :as => 'activate_user'

link_to 'Activate', activate_user_path(user.id), method: :put
```

The `activate_user` method should reside in `admins` controller. 
The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) has more info on `link_to` helper.

Comment: what does rake routes produce for above put path ?? Can you post it ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If no method is defined in the link_to, I get a No route matches [GET] error message.

Comment: The link_to-helper will do a GET unless you specify a method. So this answer is at least partially incorrect. Downvoting.

Comment: Does not work without `:method=>:put`.  Should not have been accepted.

Comment: It only works if you change your routes. Please look at the answer closely before downvoting.

Comment: With Rails 7, this should be `, data: { 'turbo-method': :put }`

Answer (score 32):

`link_to` thinks that `:method => :put` is part of the path hash. You have to tell it otherwise. Wrap your path in brackets.

```
link_to 'Activate', {:action => :activate_user, :id => user.id}, :method => :put
```

Now `link_to` will recognize `:method => :put` as an option, not part of the link's path.

As a side note, you should try to use route helpers instead of path hashes whenever possible. Keeps things nice and tidy, and avoids nit-picky situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using `link_to` do then you can use the following syntax

```
<%= link_to admin_subscription_path(user), method: :put do %>
 # can put html & css here
<% end %>
```